# How to declare copy constructor in derived class, without default construcor in base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

Please take a look on the following example:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int m_nValue;

public:
    Base(int nValue)
        : m_nValue(nValue)
    {
    }

    const char* GetName() { return "Base"; }
    int GetValue() { return m_nValue; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int nValue)
        : Base(nValue)
    {
    }
    Derived( const Base &d ){
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }

    const char* GetName() { return "Derived"; }
    int GetValueDoubled() { return m_nValue * 2; }
};
```

This code keeps throwing me an error that there are no default contructor for base class. When I declare it everything is ok. But when i dont, code does not work.

How can I declare a copy constructor in derived class without declaring default contructor in base class?

Thnaks.

Comment: Compiler doesn't supply the default constructor for the class once we have any parameterized constructor..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Call the copy-constructor (which is generated by the compiler) of the base:

```
Derived( const Derived &d ) : Base(d)
{            //^^^^^^^ change this to Derived. Your code is using Base
    std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
}
```

And ideally, you should call the compiler generated copy-constructor of the base. Don't think of calling the other constructor. I think that would be a bad idea.

Comment: @amit: `Base(Base const&)` will be generated by the compiler!

Comment: @amit: of course it is. unless you define a copy ctor yourself, the compiler will synthesize one for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can (and should) call the copy ctor of the base class, like:

```
Derived( const Derived &d ) :
        Base(d)
{
    std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
}
```

Note that I turned the Base parameter into a Derived parameter, since only that is called a copy ctor. But maybe you didn't really wanted a copy ctor...

Comment: `Base(Base const&)` is.  By the compiler.

Comment: @amit: of course it is. unless you define a copy ctor yourself, the compiler will synthesize one for you.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: You should explicitly mention it in your answer, I totally forgot about it :\

Comment: @amit: there is a whole lot of other basic things that are not explicitly mentioned in the answer, because they do not relate to the question, and either I explain all of them, or none. I think none is more useful here.

Answer (score -1):

If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), **the compiler will always declare a default constructor and a copy constructor as a non-explicit** inline public member of its class.

If some user-declared constructors are present, the **user may still force the automatic generation of a default constructor by the compiler that would be implicitly-declared otherwise with the keyword default**.

In the base constructor, you have user-declared constructors so you must declare otherwise with the keyword default.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int m_nValue;

public:
    Base(const Base&) = default;    // since cpp11

    Base(int nValue)
        : m_nValue(nValue)
    {
    }

    const char* GetName() { return "Base"; }
    int GetValue() { return m_nValue; }
};
```

In the derived constructor, you must construct base constructor like:

```
Derived(const Base &d)
: Base(d)
{
    std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to add anything to the existing eight-year-old answers; it also doesn't correct the copy ctor param