# Why is user defined copy constructor calling base constructor while default copy constructor doesn't?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

Consider the following example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {
            cout<<"constructor A called: "<<this<<endl;  
        };
        
        A(A const& other) = default;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B()
        {
            cout<<"constructor B called: "<<this<<endl;  
        };
        
        //This calls A's constructor
        B(B const& other)
        {
            cout<<"B copy constructor called: "<<this<<endl;    
        };

        //While this doesn't call A's constructor
        //B(B const& other) = default;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    
    B b2(b);

    cout<<"b: "<<&b<<endl;
    cout<<"b2: "<<&b2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor A called: 0x7fffc2fddda8
constructor B called: 0x7fffc2fddda8
constructor A called: 0x7fffc2fdddb0
B copy constructor called: 0x7fffc2fdddb0
b: 0x7fffc2fddda8
b2: 0x7fffc2fdddb0
```

Why is the **constructor of A** is called when copying B?
Shouldn't the **copy constructor of A** be called instead?

However, if you change class B's copy constructor to be **default**, the constructor of A is **not called** when copying which makes sense.

It will be nice if someone can give a reasonable explanation as to why.

Comment: Appropriate base class constructors always are called prior to the derived classes ones. I don't fully understand your concerns?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have edited my question, I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: `B(B const& other) { ... }` doesn't ask for the copy constructor. That would be `B(B const& other): A(other) { ... }`

Comment: @user4581301 Sure that will call A's copy constructor and won't call A's constructor right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the implicit copy constructor calls the base class copy constructor and the defined copy constructor doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178204/why-does-the-implicit-copy-constructor-calls-the-base-class-copy-constructor-and) or perhaps [How to declare copy constructor in derived class, without default construcor in base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309577/how-to-declare-copy-constructor-in-derived-class-without-default-construcor-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the **constructor of A** is called when copying B? Shouldn't the **copy constructor of A** be called instead?

No, it shouldn't.

A derived class must always initialize a base class.  If the derived class has a constructor that is implemented explicitly by the user, but it does not explicitly call a base class constructor in its [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), the compiler will make an implicit call to the base class's **default** constructor, *regardless* of the type of the derived constructor.  The compiler does not make any assumption about the user's intent in implementing the derived constructor.  If the user wants a specific base class constructor to be called, they need to make that call themselves.

Since `B` has an explicitly implemented copy constructor that lacks a member initialization list, the compiler initializes `A` by calling its **default** constructor, not its **copy** constructor.

IOW, this:

```
B(B const& other)
{
    ...
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
B(B const& other) : A()
{
    ...
}
```

NOT to this, as you are thinking:

```
B(B const& other) : A(other)
{
    ...
}
```

> However, if you change class B's copy constructor to be **default**, the constructor of A is **not called** when copying which makes sense.

Correct, a `default`'ed copy constructor will call the base class's copy constructor, not its default constructor.  The compiler is implicitly implementing the *entire* derived constructor, and so it will choose the appropriate base class constructor to call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense now.